# Related block by entity reference

Tags: views, 8, entities

I have a 2 content types.

1. Article
2. Page

and the Article content type can reference pages from an entity reference field.

Now I want to display a block on Article nodes that have a same reference.

So I tried this:

1. Create a views block listing Articles.
2. Add some fields.
3. Add a relationship `field_page_reference: Content`
4. Add contexual filters of `Content Id` and provide default value to **Content Id From URl** and **Specify validation criteria** set to Content and select article.

But it doesn't work? Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track, but you're missing another Relationship.

You've added the Relationship that points to a referenced Page. Now you can show that Page info in your views, but that isn't what you want. You want to show all other articles that reference that page (siblings).

To do that you need to add another Relationship that goes in reverse, from Page back to article: **Content using field_page_reference** and make it use the first Relationship (this is where the matching is happening!).

Then modify your ID Contextual filter to use the *second* Relationship.

Now you'll have a list of all articles that reference the page that is referenced on the article you're currently viewing.

---

That includes the current article BTW, so if you want to exclude it from the list you have to add *another* ID Contextual filter "Content Id From URl" but don't use any Relationships and under `More` select **Exclude**.

Comment: Thanks a million, it worked like charm, is this correct if I want to show articles block that reference to into **page** content type ?

Comment: I mean what should i do if I want to display related articles into **page** content type?

Comment: Currently, I'm able to show articles with the same reference now I want to display articles related to a **page** on the **page**

Comment: Thanks found the answer : https://www.sandstormdesign.com/blog/relationships-and-contextual-filters-in-views-3-for-drupal

Comment: As you already found, the configuration is a bit different, to show a block of Articles that reference a Page use the "Pulling fields of “Child” nodes by node reference:" part of that article.