# related by entity reference module views in Drupal 9

Tags: views

I have two content types:

Company:

- body
- field_events (Entity reference)

Events

- body
- field_company (Entity reference)

I have created a view that has this setup:

**View Settings**:

**Fields**:

- (field_events: Content) Content: Title

**Filter Criteria**:

- Content: Published (= Yes)
- Content: Content type (= Company)

**Contextual Filters**:

- (field_events: Content) Content: ID

**Relationship**:

- field_events: Content

[image]

I have followed the instructions from: [Related block by entity reference](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/277204/related-block-by-entity-reference)

My goal is to display similar events from the same company but excluding the current event shown in the page.

What step am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Follow the steps and let me know if you face the same issue

1. Click on the "advanced" tab.
2. Click on add under "contextual filters".
3. Choose Content:nid.
4. Under "when the filter variable is not available, choose "provide default value".
5. From the drop down menu select "content id from url".
6. Scroll all the way down to the bottom of the window and click on the "More" link.
7. Click "Exclude"